# ProgressBar in Recyclerview with Java

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, progress-bar

For Home fragment, I use a ProgressBar in in RecyclerView.Adapter. When the App starts everything render without problem. But when I come back from the other fragment with this code:

```
Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_nav_dashboard_to_boxFragment);
```

Then the ProgressBar will be rendered for all recycler items with the same state

```
holder.progressBar.setProgress(percent, true);
```

Comment: What does your bindViewHolder method look like?

Answer (score 0):

RecyclerView uses one view multiple times, when it contains the list which is not displaying on the screen at a time(means a list contain large amount of items which is not displaying on screen at same time you need to scroll up and down). When user scroll the list the offscreen items are reused to display the remaining list items which is called recycling.

To Stop recycling the items call this method in your onBindViewHolder method:

```
holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
```

Comment: This completely defeats the purpose of the recycler view and can lead to performance problems.

Comment: There is no different with setIsRecyclable method.

Comment: #samJoos Are You Add In onBindViewHolder Not in ViewHolder Definition?

@TheLibrarian I Agree with you, May Be found performance problems, But He don't Share a full code with us, and this is faster solution.